# VSTS Windows Machine file copy robocopy error

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Getting error when copying the files using windows machine file copy in vsts:

### [error]The term 'robocopy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Are you running it on a private agent? A hosted agent? If a hosted agent, which one? If a private agent, what OS?

Comment: Can you provide the detail log here?

Comment: @Daniel : We tried the things from Hosted Agent and Private(On-Premise) Agent.

Comment: We're seeing the same thing with TFS 2017 - we're running it on different agents, both on Windows 10 and Server 2016. It seems like an issue with TFS task, as running robocopy locally works...